# Update using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to update field using other fields in a single query ?

sql:

```
"UPDATE table_name SET field1=fields2 + 1 where id=123"
```

Tried these things, but didn't work

```
Model.update(123, :field => "field2 + 1")
Model.update(123, :field => :field2 + 1)
Model.update(123, "field = field2 + 1")
```

Don't want to do it in 2 query.

Comment: try Model.update(123, field1: "#{field2+1}") and be sure that you have access to your model attribute

Comment: @BuDen this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model.update_all("field = field2 + 1", {:id => 123})
```

The second argument is conditions, on which the update should happen

Comment: Giving "NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for :field2:Symbol"